# Firmware and Windows 10 time discrepancy

Tags: windows-10, bios, time, firmware

I have an MSI X399 motherboard and Windows 10 OS.

I had an issue with my time shown being wrong by -1 hour (and this morning -2 hours due to the clocks going forward last night). I tried several options in the Windows 10 environment, but to no avail. So every time I made a change in Windows 10, rebooted, the false time was still shown.

**Solution:** OK, so I solved this by changing the time in BIOS, then the matter is somehow solved. Though I'm not totally happy with this, because I would have expected that this would have been resolved in Windows 10 itself. So what happens when the clocks go back, do I need to change again in BIOS (instead of it automatically being corrected)?

Comment: are you dual booting other OSes? Did you set the BIOS time as UTC option?

Comment: @phuclv: No, although I did have Ubuntu19 originally, then I switched Windows 10 (first  time I've  flashed an OS on a  computer). When you say set  BIOS time, I set this yesterday, but not sure where the link with UTC is (is this in the BIOS itself o Windows)?

Comment: you *install* Windows, not *flash* it like flashing a firmware to an embedded system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux and other OSes use UTC time (without any time offset or modification like DST) but Windows uses local time (including DST) by default due to legacy reasons. Since you used Ubuntu previously and just started Windows the first time, it's expected that Windows will show the current BIOS time as local time until the next synchronization period. You can force Windows to sync right away by opening *Date and time settings* and press **Synchronize your clock**

If you're running other OSes you should [change Windows to use UTC time](https://superuser.com/q/975717/241386) or [change Linux to use local time](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows#Time_standard) (not recommended)

> So what happens when the clocks go back, do I need to change again in BIOS (instead of it automatically being corrected)?

All modern OSes will automatically sync the time periodically if there's internet connection. There's zero need for human intervention. However if you continue to dual boot you'll have the same issue: after logging into Ubuntu the time will be wrong until Ubuntu syncs the time, and then when you log back into Windows the time will be wrong until Windows syncs the time. As said, you must change all the OSes to the same time system

See also

- [UTC in Windows](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_time#UTC_in_Windows)
- [Windows 10 Clock Occasionally Displays +5 hours Upon Startup](https://superuser.com/q/1188018/241386)
- [Should I set my BIOS to local time or UTC?](https://superuser.com/q/282551/241386)
- [Clock time is off on dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/169376/253474)
- [How to Fix Windows and Linux Showing Different Times When Dual Booting](https://www.howtogeek.com/323390/how-to-fix-windows-and-linux-showing-different-times-when-dual-booting/)

Comment: I'm not sure what local time was used (whether it was using GMT) becuase my local time is  CET, so this would  have not been an issue. As I wrote, I had to change the time in the BIOS, so FW, before it permantly changed the time every time on reboot. In my BIOS (msi x399 bios5) there  doesn't appear to be the option to set  local or UTC)

Comment: @pymat CET is UTC+2 and time in Ubuntu is UTC, so obviously it's a problem. Windows is using BIOS time as local time so it's showing -2 hours difference. Once you change the BIOS time to your local time then Windows will show that. But you don't need to do that. Just let Windows sync the time

Comment: @pymat if you don't believe just change BIOS time and Windows will show that wrong time again, and then press sync to see the time being updated to the correct time by Windows

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned, you can change Windows's behavior of using UTC or local time as the system clock.

Anyway, this setting is transparent to the user interface. Only in the system BIOS/UEFI, you can notice the difference, as the OSes should synchronize with the internet. Both Windows and Linux should be configured accordingly.

See also :  [How-To Geek - How to Fix Windows and Linux Showing Different Times When Dual Booting](https://www.howtogeek.com/323390/how-to-fix-windows-and-linux-showing-different-times-when-dual-booting/)

Simple registry edits :  [**Make Windows Use UTC Time.zip**](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Make-Windows-Use-UTC-Time.zip)